# Doctrine "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" annotation (Symfony2)

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I need to make annotation for column in my entity - "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" attribute. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use your own column definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 */
private $updatedAt;
```

The example is for MySQL. Take into account, that `columnDefinition` is **not portable** among different databases or even their versions.

Comment: Hello did you mean to say "You **can** use your own column definition"?

Comment: orm update will not recognize the changes ...

From doctrine docs

columnDefinition: (optional) Allows to define a custom DDL snippet that is used to create the column. Warning: This normally confuses the SchemaTool to always detect the column as changed.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use DoctrineExtensions with Timestampable as described here: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md